# Live check user availability LDAP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ldap

I have a form in LDAP where i can add a user and a password, what can i do to have a live check of the username using php and ajax, is not mysql and i don't know how to compare and switch commands like sqlquery or sql_num_rows  used in mysql and move it to LDAP, i read LDAP manual on php and is different than mysql how can i replace this commands in LDAP so i can have my username checked live?? using javascript (everything uspposed to be in one page)

http://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Check-User-Sign-Up-Name-Ajax-PHP-Social-Network-Tutorial

https://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/how-to-check-username-availability-in.html

and other web pages tried and working with mysql

i used ldap_connect, ldap_bind_ ldap_search, ldap get entries and is working printing out everythng in funny way, so using php i cleaned out everything and is printing in a nice manner everything, my question is how can i check live the username??? Like is happening (tested) i this link above???

```
<label for="name"><b>name</b></label>
<input type="text" name="name" onBlur="checkusername() "maxlength="15"value="">
<span id="namestatus"></span>

<script>
function checkusername(){
  var status = document.getElementById("namestatus");
   var u = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if(u != ""){
    status.innerHTML = 'checking...';
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
      }
    }
        var v = "name="+u;
        hr.send(v);
  }
}
</script>

$user = 'cn=Manager,dc=mydc ,dc=it';
$password = 'mypass';
$host = 'my_numeric_IP';
$basedn = 'ou=sistem,ou=thinks,dc=mydc,dc=it';
$ds = ldap_connect("ldap://{$host}") or die('Could not connect to LDAP     server.'); 
if($ldapbind){
$filter='(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=*))'; // single filter
$attributes=array('dn','uid','sn', 'displayName');
$search = ldap_search($ds,$basedn,$filter,$attributes); // search
ldap_sort($ds, $search, 'sn');
print_r($info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search));
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
$ldaprecord['cn'] = $_POST['name'];
$_dn = "uid=".$_POST[value'].",ou=".$_POST['othervalue'].",ou=VOIP,ou=sistem,dc=something,dc=it";
$r = ldap_add($ds, $_dn, $ldaprecord);
}else {
echo "LDAP bind failed";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a little bit more difficult than only replace the mysql functions because of the mysql (or other SQL server) is not similar to LDAP.
I suggest to use an existing PHP package for LDAP. For example [Adldap2](https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2/) looks good for me. And there is many code snippets. For example the [authentication](https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2/#/setup?id=authenticating)